# Can the association ends have the same name?

Tags: class, uml, diagram, class-diagram

For example, imagine a diagram where there are 2 association ends such  as incoming/outgoingRoads. Is it possible to store these roads together in the same arraylist by giving them the same name like "allRoads" that contains both incoming and outgoing?

Or is there other way to solve this?

naming both of them with same name in uml app brings no errors

Comment: There is no picture, but you can name associations ends as you please.

Comment: The properties must be unique within their owner. If the classes on the ends each own a property, there is no problem; but, if the association owns both ends, they must have unique names.

Comment: I reworded "see the diagram" into "imagine a diagram",  since the picture is not really needed to understand the question,  and the question is relevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two association ends at the opposite side of the same class are not allowed to have the same role name. It would create a naming ambiguity for `City.allRoad`:

[image]

Two association ends at the opposiste side of different classes can have the same role name. There would be no ambiguity between `City.allRoad` and `WorkOrder.allRoad`

[image]

Two ends of the same association can have the same role name as well.  There would be no ambiguity between `City.direction` and `Road.direction`:

[image]

In the same way,  there is no problem of having two associations between the same classes but with different end names:

[image]

Your design could as well deal with only one association for both incoming and outgoing roads.  At least three different design could be considered:

- making the road graph bidirectional, i.e. if all incoming routes are at the same time outgoing roads (caution: this is a substantial change in the underlying model: it would for example not allow to represent one-way roads)
- using an association class, that would tell for each associated road, if it's incoming or outgoing.

  [image]
- using a qualifier (which would probably be implemented as a map or a 2d array, as qwerty_so mentioned in the comments):

  [image]

Comment: You made all sorts of naming but non where one association has the same name on both sides (like `-next`
 for a chain).

Comment: @qwerty_so indeed, but in my models, next on one side often has previous on the opposite side ;-)

Comment: That would be a self-reference. I was thinking of `Block`---`Marble` with `next`
 on both sides.

Comment: Reading again you could probably suggest an array of dimension 2 named `allRoads` which needs an in/out index. And a hint that this would be a bad model.

Comment: @qwerty_so That’s a good idea as well. So a qualifier on the city side? with an enum in/out... I completed the answer with the two missing points

Comment: thank you very much for your answers it really clears a lot of cases that were unclear.

Comment: I would think you need only a multiplicity of 2 and a constraint for the qualifier. But without seeing the details of the OP's question it would be just more guessing. (N.B. Honestly I think that answerers should _not_ edit the question to fit their answer; even if the OP had intended something along the lines...)